# bootstrap 4 file input button display inline-block

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have created an input file button and I want to set it to fullwidth (display:block).
I have hidden the input field but still don't see a difference. Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='mutlipart/form-data'>
  <label for="uploadAvatar">
                    <p style="display:block" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-3">Upload new avatar</p>
                    <input type="file" id="uploadAvatar" name="uploadAvatar" style="display:none">
                </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not add the display style properties to the HTML, because by default all form elements in Bootstrap are `display: block` and `width: 100%`.

Besides, you can use native Bootstrap 4 class utilities, like:

`d-block` : to display block any element
`btn-block` : to display block a btn element or an element with the `btn` class.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  </div>
</form>


<form method='POST' action='' enctype='mutlipart/form-data'>
  <label for="uploadAvatar" class="d-block">
    <p class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-sm mt-3">Upload new avatar</p>
    <input type="file" id="uploadAvatar" name="uploadAvatar" style="display:none">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `col-12` to the label.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='mutlipart/form-data'>
  <label for="uploadAvatar" class="col-12">
                    <p style="display:block" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-3">Upload new avatar</p>
                    <input type="file" id="uploadAvatar" name="uploadAvatar" style="display:none">
                </label>
</form>
```